# call by phone number on button click (java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a call method on button click

```
button_call=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_call);

button_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+79142214017"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And the data transfer method in Firebase

```
private void validateClientInfo() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(client_edit.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Введите имя", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(client_number.getText().toString())){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Введите номер", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {
        HashMap<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("uid", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());          
                    userMap.put("numberphone_client",client_number.getText().toString());

     clientRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);

        startActivity(new Intent(ClientName.this,HomeActivity.class));
    }
}
```

transcripts

```
client_number=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.client_number);
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

how to make it so that when the call button is pressed, the number is received and called?

I want that when the button _call button is pressed, the data transmitted by the transfer method is received and a call is made on them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1):

### Request permission **android.permission.CALL_PHONE** before calling.

Add into **AndroidManifest.xml**:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Request permission **before** calling:

```
boolean isPermissionGranted = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

if (isPermissionGranted) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mNumber));
    
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Отсутствует разрешение на звонок с устройства", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE }, 0);
}
```

Add **request result**:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull @NotNull String[] permissions, @NonNull @NotNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        for (int result : grantResults) {
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //RETURN, PERMISSION NOT GRANTED

                Toast.makeText(this, "Вы не выдали разрешение, приложение может работать неккоректно!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }

        //PERMISSIONS GRANTED
        Toast.makeText(this, "Спасибо за выданное разрешение!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking to call the selected number then just use the following code.

```
Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); // ACTION_CALL
        Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", "79142214017, "#");
        intentCallForward.setData(uri2);
        startActivityForResult(intentCallForward, 101);
```